# PHP repetindo comandos

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Eai galerinha, tudo bem?

estou tendo um problema do qual não consigo encontrar a solução, já dei uma pesquisada, porém nada

a uns dias atrás criei uma pergunta aqui, sobre como executar apenas 1x quando clicado em um botão, pois estava duplicando as coisas, segue o link:

(é aqui do site mesmo)
[Como resetar um botão após ser clicado? função .one](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/480058/como-resetar-um-bot%c3%a3o-ap%c3%b3s-ser-clicado-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-one)

até ai meio que achei um ajuste técnico para "solucionar" o meu problema, mas ainda assim as vezes ele está duplicando

o botão aciona um comando via AJAX

```
    $('#btnsalvar').click(function(){

                dados=$('#frmver').serialize();

                caminho = "../procedimentos/categorias/adicionar.php";
    

                $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:dados,
                url:caminho,
                success:function(r){
                    if(r == 1){

                        $('#tabelacat').load("categorias/tabelacat.php");
                        $('#tabelasub').load("categorias/tabelasub.php");
                        alertify.success("Salvo");
                    }
                }
                });
            });
```

e chega neste comando

```
    public function adicionar($dados){
        $c = new conectar();
        $conexao=$c->conexao();

        $sql = "INSERT into categorias (tipo, categoria ) VALUES ('$dados[0]', '$dados[1]')";

        return mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
    }
```

Está funcionando "perfeitamente" no localhost, mas online, as vezes da algum tipo de bug que acaba inserindo duas vezes o comando, como eu poderia resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução seria dentro do "click" você desabilitar o funcionamento do botão
e na resposta do ajax vc reabilitar o botão. Isso vai prevenir submits duplicados.

VC pode melhorar ainda mais colocando por exemplo um "spinner" nesse botão desabilitado isso também induz ao usuário a esperar concluir a ação que ele requisitou.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o plugin **jQuery LoadingOverlay**

https://gasparesganga.com/labs/jquery-loading-overlay/

```js
$('#btnsalvar').click(function(){
    dados=$('#frmver').serialize();
    caminho = "../procedimentos/categorias/adicionar.php";
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:dados,
        url:caminho,
        beforeSend:function(){
            $("#btnsalvar").LoadingOverlay("show");
        },
        success:function(r)
        {
            if(r == 1)
            {
                $("#btnsalvar").LoadingOverlay("hide");
                $('#tabelacat').load("categorias/tabelacat.php");
                $('#tabelasub').load("categorias/tabelasub.php");
                alertify.success("Salvo");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-loading-overlay@2.1.7/dist/loadingoverlay.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: testei aqui, a primeira vista, perfeito! obrigado! farei em tudo e verificarei se acabam os erros, volto para comentar novamente